# How efficient is to minify php

Tags: php, performance, minify, processing-efficiency

As asked above, is it really worth it to minify PHP scripts?

By "minify", of course, I mean remove all blank spaces, give shorter names to variables and functions and so on

Comment: why ?... php is not sended  to the client,  is executed  server side so the presence of the blanck don't is important as for javascript and css

Comment: PHP scripts run on the server. Minification has the purpose of reducing file size. So unless your server has the storage space of a router (and probably not even then), minification will have no effect at all. You don't send the PHP file to the client, you send the generated HTML/CSS/JS. _Those_ can be minified for bandwidth/speed gains. You'd likely get more performance out of caching though.

Comment: Yeah, but I was thinking that since PHP is an interpreted language, the less stuff has to be read by the interpreter, the faster it will run, isn't it?

Comment: @ZioCain perhaps in principle, but in practice, the effect will be negligible and it's likely spending the time to minify it will be more work than the work you'll save the interpreter. Minification reduces size, so unless the interpreter you're running the script on is not optimized at all or poorly written, the only case where minification will truly matter is when you have to transfer the script itself over a network or store it.

Comment: Marked as duplicate... Obviously it isn't though. Good job guys, good job...

Comment: @Nic how is this not a duplicate?

Comment: Yeah, it is a duplicate! I just couldn't find the "primary" question

Comment: @MechaLynx OP wants to know if there's a gain by minifying PHP scripts. The "duplicate" only discusses removing whitespace, but not on renaming variables and functions, removing comments, and all the other minifying techniques.

Comment: @ZioCain ah, so the verdict is guilty without proof :) I know I'm being a bit dramatic, but I'm just making a point. If you can't find a decent duplicate, then it shouldn't be marked as such.

Comment: I totally get your point! But the differences are minimal, therefore it can be marked as duplicate, IMO

Comment: @Nic fair enough, but it seems the OP feels like it is a duplicate. The issue with questions like this one is that when you know the answer, questions that are not identical can seem to be because they have the same answer regardless (plus, usually you have to try and interpret what the _actual_ question is). There is a degree to which the moderation and handling has to be more practical than strictly correct. You could have just stated your reasons in the comment, is my point.